# Doing HTTP call from inside forEach and if condition gives 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void' error

Tags: angular

Below is my service method:

```
    public saveCustomFieldsData(customAttributes) {    
        // return this.httpc.post(url, customAttributes, {headers: httpOptions.headers})
        //   .pipe(map(res => res));  //Working
        
        customAttributes.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
          if(arrayItem.action == 'edit') {
            return this.httpc.post(url, customAttributes, {headers: httpOptions.headers})
            .pipe(map(res => res));  //Not working
          }
        });
    }
```

I am calling this from my component

```
    this.customFieldsService.saveCustomFieldsData(this.customAttributes).subscribe((res: any[]) => {
        // logic
    });
```

This is working with commented code which does not have the `if` condition. But when I try to move this HTTP call inside `forEach` and `if` condition, I am getting `Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'` error. How do I modify my code to work from inside `forEach` and `if` condition?

Comment: If you actually typed your function, the compiler could tell you there's a problem. You don't return anything from `saveCustomFieldsData`, returning in the callback to `.forEach` is **not** the same thing (and is ignored for that method anyway).

Comment: I am not getting how can I modify my code wrt angular context.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve. If you just want to return the first one reached, for example, use a regular `for` loop, so the `return` is actually inside `saveCustomFieldsData`.